# zend framework install issue with include_path

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, installation, include-path

I am trying to install Zend Framework for the first time, I am running WAMP. I downloaded the file and unzipped it and moved it into C:\wamp\bin\php\

I added the path to the library into the environmental variables. Variable Name: path, Variable Value: C:\wamp\bin\php\zend_framework\library

I verified the php.ini file in use through the php_info(). I opened it and set the path to the zend library. 
include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\zend_framework\library;C:\wamp\bin\php\PEAR-1.9.4;"

When I open a cmd line and type zf, I get this:

********************** *ZF ERROR* ***************************
In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
is inside your include_path.  There are a variety of ways that you can
ensure that this zf command line tool knows where the Zend Framework
library is on your system, but not all of them can be described here.

The easiest way to get the zf command running is to give it the include
path via an environment variable ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH or
ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND with the proper include path to use,
then run the command "zf --setup".  This command is designed to create
a storage location for your user, as well as create the zf.ini file
that the zf command will consult in order to run properly on your
system.

Example you would run:

$ ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/library zf --setup

Your are encourged to read more in the link that follows.
Zend_Tool & CLI Setup Information
(available via the command line "zf --info")
   * Home directory found in environment variable HOMEPATH with value \Users\TOS
H
   * Storage directory assumed in home directory at location \Users\TOSH/.zf/
   * Storage directory does not exist at \Users\TOSH/.zf/
   * Config file assumed in home directory at location \Users\TOSH/.zf.ini
   * Config file does not exist at \Users\TOSH/.zf.ini

### To change the setup of this tool, run: "zf --setup"

php -i works from the cmd line.

OS: Windows 7 64bit
PHP v. 5.3.9
Apache 2.2.21

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php.ini for CLI is different from the one you open using wamp which is for webserver (apache)

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini
```

you should add include_path in following ini aswell

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\php.ini
```

Note
depending upon your versions of php , apache path could be little different.